# regular expression to parse string from url

Tags: regex, google-chrome-extensions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN0Ik.png)I have added one chrome extension named Tab Modifier. My aim is to automatically rename tabs using the URL.

For example: if the url is cdets.company.com/blah/ABCde12345&xyz=1/... , then I want to tab tile to display only the variable part "de12345", because the part before that remains same (like for ABCef67890, the path will be cdets.company.com/blah/ABCef67890). (I can easily put the title as ABC, but that's of no use to me.)

Now the Tab Modifier extension asks for regex. For title it says:

'You can inject any DOM content with {selector}. Examples: {title} for website title, {h1}, {#id}, {.class}, etc.'

And for URL matcher it says:

'Advanced usage: regular expression to search string fragments and use it inside the title.'
But I don't know what to input in these to get the tab title as what I need.

Comment: Without some concrete example of such an URL we won't know either. Consider using the URL and playing around on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/). Your above example doesn't have anything that separates the custom part so you'd match the whole URL which would end up with a RegEx like `<Fixed URL>(.*)&`

Comment: the custom part always is the 7 characters that follows ABC.

Comment: Yes but you'd need some kind of identifier for the start and end of those 7 characters. As the above states e.g. the static part of the URL.

Comment: can't we treat ABC as an identifier for start? And since we know there will always be 7 chars, we don't need end?

Comment: Yes, you could. Go to the website I linked above and play around with the regex the same comment contains. It should be possible to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your example URL was `cdets.company.com/blah/ABCde12345&xyz=1/`, the part you want to catch is `de12345`.

With this information you need a static part in front of the part you want to catch. An example would be the whole part of `cdets.company.com/blah/ABC` or at least `/ABC`. Using that information and the regular expression from the comment (`<Fixed URL>(.*)&`) you will end up with something like this: `\/ABC(.*)&`

There might be problems with this regex as it will only match if there is a ampersand in the URL and won't match on a URL without an ampersand.

Comment: I have added a screenshot, can you tell me what I should write in the space above 'Advance usage:' . `cdets.company.com/blah/ABC/(.*)&` worked in Regex101, but not there.

Comment: Looks like you already got your answer on the [github page](https://github.com/sylouuu/chrome-tab-modifier/issues/39) for the project?